# Paypal Parallel Payment with Multiple Currencies

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Paypal Parallel payment allow sending payment to multiple merchants. But is it possible to send multiple payment that consists of different currencies to multiple merchants?

### Sender

50.00 SGD -> Merchant 1

25.00 USD -> Merchant 2

20.00 USD -> Merchant 3

Answer (score 1):

When multiple payments are passed in one transaction, all of the payments must have the same currency code.