# Paypal Parallel Payments using different / multiple currencies

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am done searching the net for possible solutions and have finally decided to get help personally from you guys.

I am setting up parallel payments where merchants can use different currencies. In my example, both currencies are supposedly supported: USD and PHP (Philippine peso). Here are my request parameters:

```
--------------------------------------------------

[METHOD] => SetExpressCheckout
[VERSION] => 98.0
[USER] => ******************
[PWD] => *******************
[SIGNATURE] => *********************************************
[RETURNURL] => http://somewhere.com
[CANCELURL] => http://somewhere.com

[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 1319.64
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 1319.64
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => PHP
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID] => kyledomingo@gmail.com
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTREQUESTID] => CHANGETHISREQUESTID-0
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION] => Order

[PAYMENTREQUEST_1_AMT] => 28
[PAYMENTREQUEST_1_ITEMAMT] => 28
[PAYMENTREQUEST_1_CURRENCYCODE] => USD
[PAYMENTREQUEST_1_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID] => kyledomingo@gmail.com
[PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTREQUESTID] => CHANGETHISREQUESTID-1
[PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTACTION] => Order

--------------------------------------------------
```

If you will notice, the first payment request is in PHP while the second is in USD. Semantically, this looks fine but when I try to call SetExpressCheckout, it throws an error `10444 - The transaction currency specified must be the same as previously specified`.

```
--------------------------------------------------

[TIMESTAMP] => 2013-05-23T02:21:35Z
[CORRELATIONID] => 81e18fe68af6a
[ACK] => Failure
[VERSION] => 98.0
[BUILD] => 6020375
[L_ERRORCODE0] => 10444
[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Invalid Data
[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => The transaction currency specified must be the same as previously specified.
[L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error

--------------------------------------------------
```

Any pointers how to make this work? I've already browsed a lot of forums including x.com and stackoverflow but nothing seems to lead anywhere.

A similar question is at [Paypal Parallel Payment with Multiple Currencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997620/paypal-parallel-payment-with-multiple-currencies) but it is still unanswered.

Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Paypal Parallel Payment with Multiple Currencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997620/paypal-parallel-payment-with-multiple-currencies)

Answer (score 2):

When multiple payments are passed in one transaction, all of the payments must have the same currency code.

Comment: Yes I tried using just one currency and it works. But don't you think this use case of multiple currencies should also be supported? Any reasons why not?

Comment: I don't know the specifics off hand of why it was designed this way, but I would be more than happy to submit a feature request and pass this along to our development team.  However, submitting a feature request does not mean that I would have any ETA as to when or if this will be something that will be introduced.